# Find how many members are the maximum values in both their row and their column im mat

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix [N] [N] without double numbers.

The goal is to find how many members are the maximum values in both their row and their column.

Comment: Do you mean that your matrix is free of duplicates?

Comment: yes. the matrix is free of duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[rowPeaks, columnPeaks, peakCount,  peakPositions]

rowPeaks = Map[Max @ # - # &]; (* make peaks of each row  0 *)

columnPeaks = Transpose @* rowPeaks @* Transpose; (* make column peaks 0 *)


peakCount = Count[rowPeaks @ # + columnPeaks @ #, 0, All] &;

peakPositions = Position[rowPeaks @ # + columnPeaks @ #, 0] &;
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[777]
mat = Partition[RandomSample[Range[50], 25], 5];

MatrixForm @ mat
```

[image]

```
peakCount @ mat
```

> ```
>  4
> ```

```
peakPositions @ mat
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 5}}
> ```

```
MapAt[Highlighted, mat, peakPositions @ mat] // MatrixForm
```

[image]